# Why do we need to use setValue in UseState?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

So, React has UseState hook, and we should use it like this.

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(0);
```

And if we want to change a value, it should be written like this:

```
const increase = () => {
setValue(value + 1)
}
```

Why it's not possible to write it like this? Why we need setValue?

```
const increase = () => {
return value + 1;
}
```

I understand that it just doesn't work, but I couldn't find an explanation why it is like that.

Comment: Why would the return value of some function update the state? It would be very annoying to avoid returning anything just to not update the state by accident. Why if you would have two states and return both? `return value1 + value2` should both change to the sum of their values?

Comment: Because `value + 1` creates a new value with absolutely no connection to the old one, so React has no way to tell that you expect that to change the state of the component and trigger a re-render.

Comment: This is not a React question. This is a JavaScript question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The useState hook returns a function to update the state. Using setValue(value) method, you can get the previous(or old) state value to update the state.

On the other hand, without useState when you tries to increment the value, the value will not change because the react rendered the component only once and since there is no state change it won't get re-rendered, the value will remain at 0.
You can see here in details : https://dev.to/aasthapandey/why-to-use-usestate-in-react-pkf

Answer (score 1):

Answer is simple...! The state variable is directly linked to rendering your page. The state variable of useState hook is read only for the component to render it in the below return statement which renders the JSX.

The `setValue()` function not only changes the state value, but will also trigger the react to re-render the DOM which has already being painted on the browser.

Well that's a difference between an ordinary HTML page & a React App. React provides amazing framework to re-render the page automatically after the you alter the state using the `setValue()` fucntion